# App Getting Killed on Certain Android Oreo Phones AFTER ~20 MINUTES

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

i am testing my application and noticed that it is getting killed by the OS (ONLY ON OREO DEVICES) on certain devices (ON Samsung S8 there is no problem at all but on Huawei Y7 Prime the application is restarting when i open it again after having the screen off for more than 20 minutes..noting that in case i open the application directly after without waiting few minutes, then the application will open normally)

i also performed some logging to identify when and why the activity is getting destroyed but with no luck since there are no logs being written in this situation. also, i added the following code on the main activity which worked for the short time (pressing on the app icon first restarted the app on some devices but was fixed using the below code in onCreate function of the Main Activity)

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {

                isTaskRootEntered = true;
                finish();
            }
        }
```

am i missing something? please any help regarding how to fix this case would be appreciated.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** i have a foreground service that is kept on which retreives the user's location and saves it in a database. this service has a sticky notification and its working well until left for more than 20 minutes (AGAIN ONLY ON SOME DEVICES LIKE HUAWEI)

i am starting the foreground service the following way:

```
 GVGPSServiceIntent = new Intent(context, GTMStarterService.class);
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
        context.startForegroundService(GVGPSServiceIntent);
    }
    else context.startService(GVGPSServiceIntent);
```

the service looks like this

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            Notification notification = updateNotificationContent();
            startForeground("SendingPrcs".hashCode(), notification);
        }
    }

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.cancel("SendingPrcs".hashCode());
        }
    }
```

Comment: upload code you are using to start service?

Comment: i added the code as requested

Comment: It is not clear to me when what happens exactly. Your app gets destroyed after 20 minutes of the user using it or just 20 minutes after the screen is turned off? If it's the latter, then that could just be battery saving by the OS, which you can do nothing about.

Comment: it is the latter. i thought so but was just making sure since its a critical issue for the app use.

Comment: can you post your log

Comment: as i mentioned, i couldn't log any relevant data when such case happens though i had logs in the on destroy function of the activities but it never logged it. all what is available in the logs is a normal app behavior and suddenly no more logging (the app here is destroyed)